# distutils.spawn not available unless imported

Tags: python, distutils

I have `distutils` installed and it works in some cases. However when trying to use a submodule it won't import unless I explicitly import it.

```
$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 21 2020, 10:42:08) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import distutils
>>> distutils.spawn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'distutils' has no attribute 'spawn'
>>> from distutils import spawn
>>> distutils.spawn
<module 'distutils.spawn' from '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/spawn.py'>
```

I'm on Mac and have tried inside a venv and outside of one. I have a dependency that calls `distutils.spawn.find_executable('python3')` and isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. This is how Python import works. Unless [`distutils/__init__.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/__init__.py) imports `.spawn` itself (which it doesn't do) you have to import it yourself to make it available. Importing just `distutils` is not enough to access submodules.

Counterexample: `import os` makes `os.path` automatically available but that's because [`os.py` makes it available](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b3fbff7289176ba1a322e6899c3d4a04880ed5a7/Lib/os.py#L61) for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link to distutils/__init__.py, that makes sense. How did [this](https://github.com/ftpsolutions/python-third-party-license-file-generator/blob/6a2e7d241f9e2cd3f867d0ce291afe72cfbcda1f/third_party_license_file_generator/site_packages.py#L95) line ever work then. It imports distutils then direclty calls a submodule.

Comment: No idea, honestly. Gonna install it and run…

Comment: The code `python -c "import distutils, sys; print(sys.modules['distutils.spawn'])"` raises `KeyError` outside of a virtual environment. But works in a virtualenv. `python -c "import distutils, sys; print(sys.modules['distutils.spawn'])"` => `<module 'distutils.spawn' from '/home/phd/.local/lib/python2.7/distutils/spawn.pyc'>`. This is because in a venv [`distutils/__init__.py`](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/34c62baef8e3ef47d693ce0d6a7035969878db48/virtualenv.py#L1792) is quite different from stock `__init__.py` and it somehow imports `distutils.spawn`, not sure via which route.

Comment: Short resume: you better import `distutils.spawn` yourself when you need it without relying on a strange side effects.